# openstack python sdk connectivity and accessing sub modules

Tags: python, openstack

I am trying to establish a connection to openstack cloud . I am able to establish a connection with the following statement

```
from openstack import connection
conn = connection.Connection(auth_url="http://192.168.0.19:5000/v3",project_name="admin",username="admin",password="69",user_domain_id="default",project_domain_id="default")
```

I am looking for exact Connection API argument match in  connection.py file of python openstack. Also, I am looking for api to access the object store(list out files,creating backup) and network(creating subnet). I am able to create duplicate subnet in network. It doesn't prompt out any error.